# Python splitting a string on "," but a wanted content also has "," inside

Tags: python

Given a string I would like to split in every delimiter *","*. However, part of its content they find a delimiter that results to a wrong output.

As an example:

```
str = '"str1",,"str2","str,test,str3",3,5' 
print(str.split(","))

Output:
['"str1"', '', '"str2"', '"str', 'test', 'str3"', '3', '5']
```

**When what output I need is:**

```
['"str1"', '', '"str2"', '"str,test,str3"', '3', '5']
```

I also tried this using this delimiter:

```
 print(str.split('",'))
```

However, the string initially contains integers as well rendering an output:

```
['"str1', ',"str2', '"str,test,str3', '3,5']
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: is it guaranteed that there will never be whitespace outside of quotes?

Comment: Use [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shlex.html#shlex.split). You may need to tweak some instance variables; search around on StackOverflow for various examples of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The python [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module has great support to distinguishing between the delimiter inside the quote and the delimiter outside it

```
import csv
str = '"str1",,"str2","str,test,str3",3,5' 

reader = csv.reader([str])
reader.next()
```

This will produce

```
 ['str1', '', 'str2', 'str,test,str3', '3', '5']
```

Comment: hey thanks! I didn't think of using csv library on this one!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. All the best with your project